# Downloading on Android Via Retrofit2 using WorkManager Creating an Extra File Called '2811fb90a1302h'

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-workmanager

I've written code to download/upload files using retrofit 2. I'm running it with Work Manager. The code itself works fine. All the files I upload/download go to the appropriate locations, however on both the server I'm uploading to and the phone I'm downloading to files called '2811fb90a1302h' are being created. They are exactly 333 bytes. I assume it's some sort of meta data that was created. Maybe on failed attempts? But I cannot find anything programming related about it online. When I searched I just find that Snapchat was creating this file 3 years ago, so obviously they've fixed it, but that doesn't really help me. Honestly, just a more in depth description of what exactly that file is would help